# UTF16 string to normal text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one column in DB containing UTF16 string and I want to convert the UTF16 string into normal text.
 How to achieve this in c# ?

**For example :**

```
Source : 0645 0631 062D 0628 0627 0020 0627 0644 0639 0627 0644 0645
Convert : مرحبا العالم
```

Comment: What do you mean by "normal text"? UTF16 *is* normal text!

Comment: What type is your source? byte[] ?

Comment: normal text means the real text which is before converted to utf-16

Answer (score 1):

I presume that source is simply a string containing the byte values, as this is one thing not quite clear from your question.

You first need to turn that into a byte array. Of course you first need to remove the blanks.

```
// Initialize the byte array
string sourceNoBlanks = source.Replace(" ", "").Trim();
if ((sourceNoBlanks.Length % 2) > 0)
    throw new ArgumentException("The length of the source string must be a multiple of 2!");

byte[] sourceBytes = new byte[source.Length / 2];

// Then, create the bytes
for (int i = 0; i < sourceBytes.Length; i++)
{
    string byteString = sourceNoBlanks.Substring(i*2, 2);
    sourceBytes[i] = Byte.Parse(byteString, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
}
```

After that you can easily convert it to string:

```
string result = Encoding.UTF32.GetString(sourceBytes);
```

I suggest you read up on the [UTF32 encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf32encoding(v=vs.110).aspx) to understand little/big endian encoding.

Comment: `SubString` should be `Substring` and `Byte.Parse` throws a `FormatException`.

Comment: i ran the code but it is showing the error - Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length

Comment: @RameshKumarN My code assumes that the number of bytes in the source string is an exact multiple of 2 (which is logical, as one byte is represented by two characters, for example `0d` or `ff`). The fact that you get this error means that your source string - after removal of blanks - does not contain an even number of characters and thus it is not valid. I will insert code in my example to account for this fact.